# SQL - Cant use aggregate of subquery in Group clause

Tags: sql-server

Im trying to group by [DueDate] on the following query, but that date can be different depending on a setting. is there anyway I can make this work?

```
SELECT
(
    SELECT CASE 
    WHEN (SELECT TOP 1 [SiconCFMSetting].[SettingValue] FROM [SiconCFMSetting] WHERE [SiconCFMSetting].[SettingName]='UseAverageTimeToPay') = 'True'
    THEN ISNULL([SiconCFMForecastDate].[ForecastDate],DATEADD([DD],[SiconCFMSLCustomerAverageTimeToPayView].[Days],[SLPostedCustomerTran].[TransactionDate]))
    ELSE ISNULL([SiconCFMForecastDate].[ForecastDate],[SLPostedCustomerTran].[DueDate])
    END
) AS [DueDate],
SUM([SLPostedCustomerTran].[SalControlValueInBaseCurrency]) AS [Value]
FROM        [SLPostedCustomerTran]
INNER JOIN  [SLCustomerAccount]
ON          [SLCustomerAccount].[SLCustomerAccountID]
=           [SLPostedCustomerTran].[SLCustomerAccountID]
INNER JOIN  [SiconCFMSLCustomerAverageTimeToPayView]
ON          [SiconCFMSLCustomerAverageTimeToPayView].[SLCustomerAccountID]
=           [SLCustomerAccount].[SLCustomerAccountID]
LEFT JOIN   [SiconCFMForecastDate]
ON          [SiconCFMForecastDate].[ForecastDateForeignID]
=           [SLPostedCustomerTran].[SLPostedCustomerTranID]
AND         [SiconCFMForecastDate].[Deleted]=0
AND         [SiconCFMForecastDate].[ForecastDateSource]='SLPostedCustomerTran'
WHERE       ([SLPostedCustomerTran].[SYSTraderTranTypeID]=4 OR [SLPostedCustomerTran].[SYSTraderTranTypeID]=5)
AND         [SLPostedCustomerTran].[SalControlValueInBaseCurrency] <> 0
GROUP BY    
    CASE 
    WHEN (SELECT TOP 1 [SiconCFMSetting].[SettingValue] FROM [SiconCFMSetting] WHERE [SiconCFMSetting].[SettingName]='UseAverageTimeToPay') = 'True'
    THEN ISNULL([SiconCFMForecastDate].[ForecastDate],DATEADD([DD],[SiconCFMSLCustomerAverageTimeToPayView].[Days],[SLPostedCustomerTran].[TransactionDate]))
    ELSE ISNULL([SiconCFMForecastDate].[ForecastDate],[SLPostedCustomerTran].[DueDate])
    END
```

**Error :
Msg 144, Level 15, State 1, Line 26
Cannot use an aggregate or a subquery in an expression used for the group by list of a GROUP BY clause.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the aggregation in outer query. You can do this

```
with cte as
(
SELECT
(
    SELECT CASE 
    WHEN (SELECT TOP 1 [SiconCFMSetting].[SettingValue] FROM [SiconCFMSetting] WHERE [SiconCFMSetting].[SettingName]='UseAverageTimeToPay') = 'True'
    THEN ISNULL([SiconCFMForecastDate].[ForecastDate],DATEADD([DD],[SiconCFMSLCustomerAverageTimeToPayView].[Days],[SLPostedCustomerTran].[TransactionDate]))
    ELSE ISNULL([SiconCFMForecastDate].[ForecastDate],[SLPostedCustomerTran].[DueDate])
    END
) AS [DueDate],
[SLPostedCustomerTran].[SalControlValueInBaseCurrency] AS [Value]
FROM        [SLPostedCustomerTran]
INNER JOIN  [SLCustomerAccount]
ON          [SLCustomerAccount].[SLCustomerAccountID]
=           [SLPostedCustomerTran].[SLCustomerAccountID]
INNER JOIN  [SiconCFMSLCustomerAverageTimeToPayView]
ON          [SiconCFMSLCustomerAverageTimeToPayView].[SLCustomerAccountID]
=           [SLCustomerAccount].[SLCustomerAccountID]
LEFT JOIN   [SiconCFMForecastDate]
ON          [SiconCFMForecastDate].[ForecastDateForeignID]
=           [SLPostedCustomerTran].[SLPostedCustomerTranID]
AND         [SiconCFMForecastDate].[Deleted]=0
AND         [SiconCFMForecastDate].[ForecastDateSource]='SLPostedCustomerTran'
WHERE       ([SLPostedCustomerTran].[SYSTraderTranTypeID]=4 OR [SLPostedCustomerTran].[SYSTraderTranTypeID]=5)
AND         [SLPostedCustomerTran].[SalControlValueInBaseCurrency] <> 0
)
select DueDate,sum(Value)
from cte 
group by DueDate
```

To do this in singe query use `OUTER APPLY`

```
SELECT OA.[DueDate],
       Sum([SLPostedCustomerTran].[SalControlValueInBaseCurrency]) AS [Value]
FROM   [SLPostedCustomerTran]
       INNER JOIN [SLCustomerAccount]
               ON [SLCustomerAccount].[SLCustomerAccountID] = [SLPostedCustomerTran].[SLCustomerAccountID]
       INNER JOIN [SiconCFMSLCustomerAverageTimeToPayView]
               ON [SiconCFMSLCustomerAverageTimeToPayView].[SLCustomerAccountID] = [SLCustomerAccount].[SLCustomerAccountID]
       LEFT JOIN [SiconCFMForecastDate]
              ON [SiconCFMForecastDate].[ForecastDateForeignID] = [SLPostedCustomerTran].[SLPostedCustomerTranID]
                 AND [SiconCFMForecastDate].[Deleted] = 0
                 AND [SiconCFMForecastDate].[ForecastDateSource] = 'SLPostedCustomerTran'
       OUTER apply (SELECT CASE
                             WHEN (SELECT TOP 1 [SiconCFMSetting].[SettingValue]
                                   FROM   [SiconCFMSetting]
                                   WHERE  [SiconCFMSetting].[SettingName] = 'UseAverageTimeToPay') = 'True' THEN Isnull([SiconCFMForecastDate].[ForecastDate], Dateadd([DD], [SiconCFMSLCustomerAverageTimeToPayView].[Days], [SLPostedCustomerTran].[TransactionDate]))
                             ELSE Isnull([SiconCFMForecastDate].[ForecastDate], [SLPostedCustomerTran].[DueDate])
                           END) OA ([DueDate])
WHERE  ( [SLPostedCustomerTran].[SYSTraderTranTypeID] = 4
          OR [SLPostedCustomerTran].[SYSTraderTranTypeID] = 5 )
       AND [SLPostedCustomerTran].[SalControlValueInBaseCurrency] <> 0
```

Comment: Thanks, ill give it a try now!

Comment: That does the trick!, will accept the answer as soon as it lets me

Comment: @WraithNath check the another way

Comment: Thanks, I did some testing with an outer SELECT, and the WITH statement you did and both are very similar timings. would the OUTER APPLY be quicker? what made you think of trying it that way too?